# Wrong notation/domain for the functions in this system of ODEs?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, dynamical-systems

> For $x: \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ and $u:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ we have the constrained ordinary differential equation (ODE)
>   \begin{align}
> \dot x(t) &= f(x(t),u(t)) \tag 1\\
> 0&\geq h(x(t),u(t)) \tag 2
> \end{align}
>   where $f:\mathbb R^{n\times m} \rightarrow\mathbb R^n$ and $h: \mathbb R^{n\times m}\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$.

From the notation I guess the domain of $f$ and $h$ are matrices, i.e. $\mathbb R^{n\times m}$. 
But is that not a typo? Should it not be $+$ instead of $\times$? I mean the following:

$f$ and $h$ are a compositions of $x$ with the range $\mathbb R^n$ and $u$ with the range $\mathbb R^m$. Therefore 
\begin{align}
f&:\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^m = \mathbb R^{n+m} \rightarrow \mathbb R^n \tag 3
\\
g&:\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^m = \mathbb R^{n+m} \rightarrow \mathbb R^n \tag 4
\end{align}
I.e. the cartesian product of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$.

Is this correct or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is a typo. And you are missing a derivation symbol in the differential equation.